# Can I use a Unix domain socket on Android?

Tags: android, sockets, unix, localsocket

Can I use a Unix domain socket on Android (both server and client on the same Android device, for IPC)? Or, must I use LocalSocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalSocket` and `LocalServerSocket` uses Unix domain sockets internally.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalSocket

> Creates a (non-server) socket in the UNIX-domain namespace.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LocalServerSocket

> Non-standard class for creating an inbound UNIX-domain socket in the Linux abstract namespace.

Also see: [Android create Unix domain socket by bound file descriptor](https://gist.github.com/RajithaKumara/2700e362ff231da265aee25f7aa0a57a)

Comment: thanks. But found that it's not able to use domain socket in cpp for android, got this error: "bind, error: 'Read-only file system'!"

Comment: Any ideas where to find an equivalent NDK version (no Java)?